# Mask the data values inside a pie plot matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the following code to produce a pie plot.
My question is, how do I mask/hide the numbers inside the pie chart?
I do not want the numbers 0.62, 0.31 and 0.02 inside the pie chart to be visible.
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df99 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Perc': [0.62, 0.31, 0.02]})
plt.pie(df99['Perc']*100, colors=['#002c4b','#392e2c','#92847a','#ccc2bb','#6b879d','#7FBAA4','#8E654C','#006CB8','#CBBBE9','#9778D3'],counterclock=False,startangle=-270,pctdistance=1.2,labeldistance=1.2,labels=df99['Data'],
        autopct=lambda p: f"{p*df99['Perc'].sum()/100:.2f}")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df99 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Perc': [0.62, 0.31, 0.02]})
plt.pie(df99['Perc']*100, 
        colors=['#002c4b','#392e2c','#92847a','#ccc2bb','#6b879d','#7FBAA4','#8E654C','#006CB8','#CBBBE9','#9778D3'],counterclock=False,startangle=-270,pctdistance=1.2,labeldistance=1.2,
        labels=df99['Data'],
        autopct=None)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Let's use pandas plot also,

```
df99.set_index('Data').mul(100).plot.pie(y='Perc',colors=['#002c4b','#392e2c','#92847a','#ccc2bb','#6b879d','#7FBAA4','#8E654C','#006CB8','#CBBBE9','#9778D3'],counterclock=False,startangle=-270)
```

Output:

[image]